# (Beautiful) animated travel maps

Tags: windows, maps, animation

So, on Mac using iMovie it's [super easy to create animated travel maps](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH14706?locale=en_US):

[image]

Now that I am not using a Mac anymore I was wondering whether there is any cheap or free software out there which can do the same thing. Automated Blender scripts or similar solutions are fine as well.

Requirements:

- Exports a video file
- Shows a line that moves from one predefined location to another where both locations can be labeled

Nice to have:

- 3D globe

Both Windows, Linux or web based solutions are fine, though right now Window or web based would be easiest.

Comment: In that case, no tag is necessary as long as you mention it in the body of the question